# Entropy Solution of Burgers' equation $u_t+(u^2/2)_x=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

Given the initial data
$$ g(x)= \cases{ 1 & $x< -1$ \\ 0 &  $-1 < x< 0$ \\ 2 &  $0 < x< 1$ \\ 0 &  $1 < x$ \\  } $$
What is the entropy solution of Burgers' equation $u_t+(u^2/2)_x=0$?

Comment: See section [3.5.4 Shock relation](http://www.eng.fsu.edu/~dommelen/pdes/style_a/burgers.html). You will have two shock waves, starting from $x=\pm 1$ as well as a rarefaction wave emanating from $x=0$. After a while they will begin to interact, so the thing will become messy.

Comment: I have a solution written down for you, but my PDE exam is tomorrow! I will update!

Comment: I would appreciate the checkmark if my solution suffices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can first create a solution for small $t$ by simply looking at the behavior of the initial condition. Notice that at at $x=-1$ we have a shock, as we are jumping from $1$ to $0$, a rarefaction at $x=0$ as we go from $0$ to $2$, and finally a shock at $x=1$ as we go from $2$ to $0$.

At $x=-1$, the R-H condition gives $\sigma = \frac{1}{2}$, and at $x=1$, $\sigma = 1$. Thus we can form our solution as follows:

$$
u(x,t) = \left\{
\begin{array}{lc}
1 & x<-1+\frac{1}{2}t \\
0 & -1 + \frac{1}{2}t<x<0 \\
\frac{x}{t} & 0<x<2t \\
2 & 2t < x< 1+t \\
0 & x>1+t
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Notice that we have collisions at $t=2$ and $t=1$, therefore this solution only is valid for $0\leq t\leq 1$. We will have to examine each shock seperately. 
For the shock at $t=2$, we have $u_l = \frac{x}{t}$ and $u_{r} = 0$. Denote the speed of this shock according to the R-H condition by

$$ s'(t) = \frac{ \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{s(t)}{t} \right) ^2}{ \frac{ s(t)} {t}} = \frac{s(t)}{2t}$$

with $s(1)=2$ since that is the value of $x$ at $t=1$. This gives $s(t) = 2\sqrt{t}$.
For the other shock at $t=2$, we have $u_l = -1$ and $u_r = \frac{x}{t}$, so
$$q'(t) =  \frac{ \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{q(t)}{t} \right)^2 }{1 - \frac{q(t)}{t}} = \frac{1}{2} \left( 1+ \frac{q(t)}{t} \right) $$

with $ q(2) = 0 $ by the same reasoning, so that this gives
 $q(t) = t - \sqrt{2t}$. Note that these two shocks in fact will intersect eachother at $t = 6+4\sqrt{2}$, so our solution 
for $1 \leq t \leq 2$ and 
$2 \leq t \leq 6+4\sqrt{2}$ is

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lc}
1 &  x<-1+\frac{1}{2}t\\
0 & -1+\frac{1}{2}t < x <0\\
\frac{x}{t} & 0 < x < 2 \sqrt{t}\\
0 & x >2 \sqrt{t}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lc}
1 &  x<t-\sqrt{2t}\\
\frac{x}{t} & t-\sqrt{2t} < x < 2 \sqrt{t}\\
0 & x >2 \sqrt{t}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

respectively. Finally, the shock at $t=6+4 \sqrt{2}$ is given by, with $u_l = 1$, $u_r = 0$,
$$ r'(s) = \frac{1}{2}$$
with $r(6+4 \sqrt{2}) = 4+2 \sqrt{2}$. This gives $r(t) = \frac{1}{2} +1$, and so the solution for $t > 6+4 \sqrt{2}$ is given by
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lc}
1 &  x<1+\frac{1}{2}t\\
0 &  x > 1 + \frac{1}{2}t\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

This gives you a full solution, and a picture of the shocks can be seen here:
[image]

You can readily see where each portion of the solution is assigned to in the picture as well.

Comment: I don't see why $q(2)=0$ and not $q(2)=1$. Could you explain this to me?

Comment: Basically going back to the way we did it before, when $t=2$, what is the value of $x$ at the collision? That’s precisely where the shocks $x=0$ and $x=-1+\frac{1}{2}t$ intersect, giving $x=0$

Comment: Ok, thank you for answering.
And I think in your answer it should be $q(t)=t-\sqrt{2*t}$ instead of $q(t)=t=\sqrt{2*t}$.
Your answer was a great help to me.

Comment: Good catch :) 

Comment: could you please explain to me why $r(6+4\sqrt{2})=4+2\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @jigga It corresponds to the time $t^*$ where the rarefaction collapses (its domain of definition vanishes): $x^* = t^*-\sqrt{2t^*} = 2\sqrt{t^*}$ has solutions $t^* = 0$ and $t^*=6+4\sqrt{2}$. The latter option gives $x^* = 4+2\sqrt{2}$.