# Find the entropy solution of the PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am struggling with the similarity solution method laid out in Evan's PDE to find the entropy solution of a PDE. This is one example we briefly touched on in class but class ended and we never came back to it.

> Compute explicitly the entropy solution of the Burger's equation
> $$ u_{t}+\left(\frac{u^{2}}{2}\right)_{x} = 0, \text{  in  }\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty)$$
> $$u(x,0) = g(x), \text{  on  }\mathbb{R}\times{t=0}$$
> where $g(x)$ is given by
> $$0, \text{ for } x<0$$
> $$1, \text{ for } 0\leq x\leq 1$$
> $$0, \text{ for } x>1$$

I can come up with the characteristic ODEs which are
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=u$$
$$\frac{du}{dt}=0$$

This gives us $u(x,t) = constant$ and that implies (with the initial data) that $u(x,t) = g(x_{o})$ where $x_{o} = x(0)$. This in turn implies that $x(t)=x_{o}+g(x_{o})t$ as characteristics go.  I can then look specifically at the three regions and obtain

$$x_{0} < 0 \Longrightarrow g(x_{0}) = 0 \Rightarrow x(t) = x_{0} $$
$$ 0 < x_{0} < 1 \Longrightarrow g(x_{0}) = 1 \Rightarrow x(t) =x_{0} + t $$
$$ x_{0} > 1 \Longrightarrow g(x_{0}) = 0 \Rightarrow x(t) = x_{0} $$

Now we notice that projected characteristics intersect at $x=0$, therefore we need to put in a shock curve. We want $u_{r} = 1$ and $u_l = 0$ and by utilizing the RH jump condition we have the shock curve $\xi_{1}(t)$ given by
$$\xi_{1}'(t) = \frac{\frac{(u_{l}^{2})}{2}-\frac{(u_{r}^{2})}{2}}{u_{l}-u_{r}} = \frac{0 - \frac{1}{2}}{0-1} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Thus our shock curve is given by $\xi_{1}(t) = \frac{1}{2}t$, from here I have no idea what to do anymore. . .

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058321/entropy-solution-of-burgers-equation-u-tu2-2-x-0 you may find this helpful

Comment: @C4P I had seen that example, but I struggled to follow some of the logic.